# Encryption of Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I used aspnet_regiis to encrypt connection string in app.config of a C# application. But I wonder that if any one knows this method, so he can decrypt the file that exists on the client machine, is this correct? if yes, so what I benefit from encrypting the connection string! and what is the work around to stop any one from decrypting it!?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. I recommend to use a Webservice and not a Database-Connection.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, can u elaborate more on webservice? Can I combine RSA with aspnet_regiis?? I guess I came on something like this while I was searching....

Answer (score 0):

You're right, since your application needs to be able to access the key used decrypt the connection string, an attacker will be able to do so too.

Basically if your application has permission to access the database, a determined hacker who is running under the same Windows acount will also have permission to do so.

To avoid an attacker accessing the database, the secure solution is to put all your logic that accesses the database in a web service, and call the web service from your client application.

The name of the utility aspnet_regiis is a clue to the fact that it isn't suitable for providing security for client applications.